# Investigate an unknown device connected to router

Tags: network, scan

On my router(Virgin Media) I found a device labelled as "unknown" I often see the router not assigning the device name but I do have a clue about which device is.

However this specific device got me curious because in the port forwarding section, a UDP port has been assigned to the IP address of this unknown device

My question is, what steps and methods can I implement to find as much information as possible from this device?

What I did so far is this On Mac, I run a port scanner, which found port 41800 open On the terminal I run

```
sudo nmap -sS -T4 -A -p- <IP>
```

The above found port 9295 open The router has assigned UDP port 9308 to this IP address

If I do telnet on 41800,9295, it connects but I can't do anything else I can't do telnet on 9308 but I get success by running

```
nc -z -v -u <IP> 9308
```

However, I'm not being able to do anything more than this, not a clue about what kind of device it could be or anything else

What else can I do?

Thank you

Comment: How do you think we can know what device is running in your local network?

Comment: The MAC address OUI may point you to the manufacturer of the device, in case it is something you forgot about.

Comment: Go into your router and blacklist the unknown mac address. See what fails.

Comment: Also try nmap OS detection:  *sudo nmap -O -v <IP>*

Comment: Thank you. Well what I'm trying to achieve here is the possibility to get as much information about the target IP, without having to go through the router.

@user10216038  usersudo nmap -O -v <IP> that's an interesting command I wasn't aware of, I always wondered how routers get the name of the devices, the above does that

Sadly here, it's returning unknown as the router. I searched the MAC online and couldn't find any hit

Comment: When you say you searched the MAC online; did you try sites such as: *https://aruljohn.com/mac.pl* and *https://macvendorlookup.com/*

Comment: @Sgr don't search for the whole mac, just the 1st 3 groups (like 01:FF:FF __ __ __); those dictate what the manufacturer of the NIC is, that's if the MAC was not changed manually.

Comment: Yes I did use those sites but no match, the only thing that came out is Range IEEE
@Overmind I've also tried as you suggested but no result. However these sites seems to extrapolate the relevant section of the MAC address even if you provide the whole MAC

Comment: Means it was manually set which means some skill behind it.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily true.
I searched for my laptop MAC on those sites and it returned a hit.
I searched for my mobile MAC on those site but there was no result.

Comment: You may improve your question by stating the exact model of the router. I have seen at least one telecom-provided router (not Virgin Media) that contained a set-top box functions and/or voice phone functions. These additional functions were represented by different MAC and IP address on the network (it is possible that the router contained separate boards for these functions, but I never really tried to find out). If you are brave, you may try to temporarily disable the UDP port mapped to the device and find out what breaks.

Answer (score 2):

There are many free utilities that will do this. On windows I like wireless network watcher from NIRsoft. On mac, try FING

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/check-wi-fi-network-suspicious-devices/